# Found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, appending to Array, Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift3, option-type

I'm trying to add a random choice form one Array to another (code below) and am getting the error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
let list1 = ["first","second","third"]

var list2:[String]!

let num = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(2)))

list2.append(list1[num])

print("\(list1)\n\(list2)")
```

Answer (score 3):

`list2` is not initialized. While you try appending something to it, it's still `nil`.

You should initialize it first like this:

```
var list2 = [String]()
```